# How to fix: Unable to get the size of the image [] with HTML2PDF

Tags: php, image, tcpdf, html2pdf

I check other similar posts where people have the same issue but none of them were of help.

What I tried is to swap this 3 ways of path but I get same error message with all of them:

```
$logo = 'assets/company/logo-png-3.png';
$logo1 = 'https://my.hostname.co.uk/assets/company/logo-png-3.png';
$logo2 = '/home/username/my.hostname.co.uk/assets/company/logo-png-3.png';


$html = '<div>';
$html .= '<img src="'.$logo.'">';
$html .= '</div>';


  $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', 'UTF-8');
  $html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
  $html2pdf->output($file, 'F');
```

Also I set in my project directory `php.ini` file that includes:

```
allow_url_fopen = On;
allow_url_include = On;
```

But I am still getting:

> Unable to get the size of the image [] with HTML2PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved

For some reason in vendor\spipu\html2pdf\src\Html2Pdf.php

```
protected function _tag_open_IMG($param)
{

  print_r($param);

    $src    = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $param['src']);
```

im getting result like this

```
Array ( 
[style] => Array ( ) 
[alt] => 
[src] => 
[href] => https://my.hostname.co.uk/assets/company/logo-png-3.png
[num] => 1 
)
```

so i just change

```
$src    = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $param['src']);
```

to

```
$src    = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $param['href']);
```

Comment: This helped me figure out that I was using absolute url, instead of the relative file path

Answer (score 1):

So, I discovered there was a space after my *src* attribute. Apparently that is a no-no with Html2Pdf. Simply removing the space by changing:

```
src ="$imageUrl"
```

To

```
 src="$imageUrl"
```

sorted out my issue!

Answer (score 0):

in the Html2Pdf file is documented the solution.

`// WARNING : if URL, "allow_url_fopen" must turned to "on" in php.ini`//

So just enable in the php.ini that option.

Greetings!

Comment: if you read my topic you can see i have been setup this one to ON and still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023
to use images like this

```
<img src="img/admin/logo.png" alt='Logo' width="100px" >
```

Change `_drawImage` function for this

```html
    protected function _drawImage($src, $subLi = false)
    {
        // get the size of the image
        // WARNING : if URL, "allow_url_fopen" must turned to "on" in php.ini

        $imagenlocal = 1;
        if (strpos($src,'data:') === 0) {
            $src = base64_decode( preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $src) );
            $infos = @getimagesizefromstring($src);
            $src = "@{$src}";
            $imagenlocal = 0;
        } 

        if(strpos($src,'http') === 0){
            echo "entro";
            $this->parsingCss->checkValidPath($src);
            $infos = @getimagesize($src);
            $imagenlocal = 0;
        }
        
        if($imagenlocal){
            $this->parsingCss->checkValidPath($src);
            $src =$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $src;
            $infos = @getimagesize($src);
        }



        // if the image does not exist, or can not be loaded
        if (!is_array($infos) || count($infos)<2) {
            if ($this->_testIsImage) {
                $e = new ImageException('Unable to get the size of the image ['.$src.']');
                $e->setImage($src);
                throw $e;
            }

            // display a gray rectangle
            $src = null;
            $infos = array(16, 16);

            // if we have a fallback Image, we use it
            if ($this->_fallbackImage) {
                $src = $this->_fallbackImage;
                $infos = @getimagesize($src);

                if (count($infos)<2) {
                    $e = new ImageException('Unable to get the size of the fallback image ['.$src.']');
                    $e->setImage($src);
                    throw $e;
                }
            }
        }

        // convert the size of the image in the unit of the PDF
        $imageWidth = $infos[0]/$this->pdf->getK();
        $imageHeight = $infos[1]/$this->pdf->getK();

        $ratio = $imageWidth / $imageHeight;

        // calculate the size from the css style
        if ($this->parsingCss->value['width'] && $this->parsingCss->value['height']) {
            $w = $this->parsingCss->value['width'];
            $h = $this->parsingCss->value['height'];
        } elseif ($this->parsingCss->value['width']) {
            $w = $this->parsingCss->value['width'];
            $h = $w / $ratio;
        } elseif ($this->parsingCss->value['height']) {
            $h = $this->parsingCss->value['height'];
            $w = $h * $ratio;
        } else {
            // convert px to pt
            $w = 72./96.*$imageWidth;
            $h = 72./96.*$imageHeight;
        }

        if (isset($this->parsingCss->value['max-width']) && $this->parsingCss->value['max-width'] < $w) {
            $w = $this->parsingCss->value['max-width'];
            if (!$this->parsingCss->value['height']) {
                // reprocess the height if not constrained
                $h = $w / $ratio;
            }
        }
        if (isset($this->parsingCss->value['max-height']) && $this->parsingCss->value['max-height'] < $h) {
            $h = $this->parsingCss->value['max-height'];
            if (!$this->parsingCss->value['width']) {
                // reprocess the width if not constrained
                $w = $h * $ratio;
            }
        }

        // are we in a float
        $float = $this->parsingCss->getFloat();

        // if we are in a float, but if something else if on the line
        // => make the break line (false if we are in "_isForOneLine" mode)
        if ($float && $this->_maxH && !$this->_tag_open_BR(array())) {
            return false;
        }

        // position of the image
        $x = $this->pdf->GetX();
        $y = $this->pdf->GetY();

        // if the image can not be put on the current line => new line
        if (!$float && ($x + $w>$this->pdf->getW() - $this->pdf->getrMargin()) && $this->_maxH) {
            if ($this->_isForOneLine) {
                return false;
            }

            // set the new line
            $hnl = max($this->_maxH, $this->parsingCss->getLineHeight());
            $this->_setNewLine($hnl);

            // get the new position
            $x = $this->pdf->GetX();
            $y = $this->pdf->GetY();
        }

        // if the image can not be put on the current page
        if (($y + $h>$this->pdf->getH() - $this->pdf->getbMargin()) && !$this->_isInOverflow) {
            // new page
            $this->_setNewPage();

            // get the new position
            $x = $this->pdf->GetX();
            $y = $this->pdf->GetY();
        }

        // correction for display the image of a list
        $hT = 0.80*$this->parsingCss->value['font-size'];
        if ($subLi && $h<$hT) {
            $y+=($hT-$h);
        }

        // add the margin top
        $yc = $y-$this->parsingCss->value['margin']['t'];

        // get the width and the position of the parent
        $old = $this->parsingCss->getOldValues();
        if ($old['width']) {
            $parentWidth = $old['width'];
            $parentX = $x;
        } else {
            $parentWidth = $this->pdf->getW() - $this->pdf->getlMargin() - $this->pdf->getrMargin();
            $parentX = $this->pdf->getlMargin();
        }

        // if we are in a gloat => adapt the parent position and width
        if ($float) {
            list($lx, $rx) = $this->_getMargins($yc);
            $parentX = $lx;
            $parentWidth = $rx-$lx;
        }

        // calculate the position of the image, if align to the right
        if ($parentWidth>$w && $float !== 'left') {
            if ($float === 'right' || $this->parsingCss->value['text-align'] === 'li_right') {
                $x = $parentX + $parentWidth - $w-$this->parsingCss->value['margin']['r']-$this->parsingCss->value['margin']['l'];
            }
        }

        // display the image
        if (!$this->_subPart && !$this->_isSubPart) {
            if ($src) {
                $this->pdf->Image($src, $x, $y, $w, $h, '', $this->_isInLink);
            } else {
                // rectangle if the image can not be loaded
                $this->pdf->SetFillColorArray(array(240, 220, 220));
                $this->pdf->Rect($x, $y, $w, $h, 'F');
            }
        }

        // apply the margins
        $x-= $this->parsingCss->value['margin']['l'];
        $y-= $this->parsingCss->value['margin']['t'];
        $w+= $this->parsingCss->value['margin']['l'] + $this->parsingCss->value['margin']['r'];
        $h+= $this->parsingCss->value['margin']['t'] + $this->parsingCss->value['margin']['b'];

        if ($float === 'left') {
            // save the current max
            $this->_maxX = max($this->_maxX, $x+$w);
            $this->_maxY = max($this->_maxY, $y+$h);

            // add the image to the margins
            $this->_addMargins($float, $x, $y, $x+$w, $y+$h);

            // get the new position
            list($lx, $rx) = $this->_getMargins($yc);
            $this->pdf->SetXY($lx, $yc);
        } elseif ($float === 'right') {
            // save the current max. We don't save the X because it is not the real max of the line
            $this->_maxY = max($this->_maxY, $y+$h);

            // add the image to the margins
            $this->_addMargins($float, $x, $y, $x+$w, $y+$h);

            // get the new position
            list($lx, $rx) = $this->_getMargins($yc);
            $this->pdf->SetXY($lx, $yc);
        } else {
            // set the new position at the end of the image
            $this->pdf->SetX($x+$w);

            // save the current max
            $this->_maxX = max($this->_maxX, $x+$w);
            $this->_maxY = max($this->_maxY, $y+$h);
            $this->_maxH = max($this->_maxH, $h);
        }

        return true;
    }
```